# Move code from .aspx file to .cs file without any difference

Tags: c#, asp.net, head

I have some code in `<head>` in .apsx I would like to move to my .cs file. So I just move it to my Page_Load(), and it everything would result in the same? Thanks.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="da" lang="da">
<head>
    <%
        var v = new Something(); // Want to move this to .cs
    %>
</head>
</html>
```

Equal to?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var v = new Something();
}
```

Comment: Depends entirely on how you are using `v` here.

Comment: What do you want to do with this?

Comment: Interesting. I can add the real lines instead of "var v = new Something();" But I don't know if that would help. What do you think? Can I do any else to clarify? Or maybe, if anybody can point me in the right direction so I can read more about this. I don't know where to start.

Comment: @radbyx Naybe but you'll need to answer Munim Abdul's question.

Comment: @Munim I had to migrate some code from others into my code. And they use this form for inlining that I have never seen or used before. So I want to move it, so I'll get to my comform-zone :)

Comment: @asawyer I was answering you and didn't see he's comment. I can't write english fast, but your right ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by others, it depends on what your code is doing exactly.

Your code snippet `var v = new Something();` would work exactly the same.

But, the time at which those 2 pieces of code are executed is much different. Page_Load happens way before any code on the actual aspx page is run. Code on the aspx page itself doesn't run until the Render event I believe. You can look at the [Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) to see the full list of events.

Comment: Actually my Page_Load is empty at the moment, so for know I guess I would not hurt :)

Comment: @radbyx It's not so much that Page_Load is empty or has code in it, it's when things are happening that will likely matter most.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean. I am just saying that as long as my class was empty before I put anything in it, I can't break anything I think.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the scope in which you want to use v.
If you want to make it available through all the page just declare it as a class member.

Comment: Allright the scope is just this page/class, so I should be fine I guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected Something v;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     v = new Something();
}
```

That is closer to what you have, this way you can actually still use the variable in the aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

it depends where you want to move the logic - on page load or on any event fire.

Answer (score 0):

yes, or you can inherit to other name

Answer (score 0):

<% %>
run in the client render

the  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         var v = new Something();
    }
run the server page lifecycle

so you can see the article (msdn)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135(v=vs.80).aspx